# Turn some columns of dataframe to a sheet and display it in itables

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to turn some columns of my dataframe to a sheet and display it using itables. is it possible to achieve such thing? are there any other module that I can use for it since itables only accept dataframe in the param as far as I know.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYGqB.png)

this dataframe displayed in itables where "C" column is a sheet.

Comment: please attach the image as part of the question, and not as a hyperlink

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33623091/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).